# How to remove ActiveX Add on from IE 7 (normal method does not work)

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

Does anybody know how to remove an ActiveX control from Internet Explorer 7.0 ?
I had been deleting and adding this control numerous times using the built in delete button in Tools, Manage Add-ons, Enable or Disable.  This is required for me to test a downloader ActiveX used for a website.  It had always shown up in the "Downloaded ActiveX Controls (32 bit) section of the drop down which activates the delete button.  However, all of a sudden it now appears under "Add ons that have been used by Internet Explorer" and I cannot delete it from there.

The "in folder" column says it's in the C:\WINDOWS\Downloaded Program Files folder... But it does not appear to be there either...

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

Autoruns can remove IE Addons: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this control doesn't seem to be displayed in Autoruns.  Surprising since so much is there.  But I know this control is installed, because it runs...  Too weird.

Comment: I found them in the C:RECYCLER folder  It won't let me delete one though..  It has a strange name (all numbers and dashes...  I will look fot this in Autoruns.

Comment: Ok removed them from the recycler folder....  And it is still there.  This is painful!

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but I am uninstalling IE7 and will re-install.  I bet the thing will still be there though.

Comment: Yes, the ActiveX control is still there and I cannot delete it.

Comment: Can you boot another OS, and delete the file that way? I think you're seeing some corruption or something. Maybe you found a bug. What if you log in as another administrative user, and try removing it then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.  Went to Tools, Internet Options, Advanced, and press "RESET Internet Explorer Settings.  It disables most of the add-ins so take screens shots first.  You have to enable a lot of add-ons again.  But the good news is it deleted the one that should not have been in tha category not allowing the delete.  Whew!  Painful.

More info.  Actually, the reset button only removed the entry from IE.  I had to edit the registry and delete all references to the downloader activeX control and run my registry cleaner. Finally, the control was not active!

Answer (score 0):

When doing **ANY** kind of development that creates/removes/updates entries in the registry, be sure you use the (very excellent) CCLeaner. It will nicely remove any "dangling" references you (most certainly) have created in the registry ...
(yes there are other, but believe me this one you want to use)

--DBJ

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a program that does the trick.  [XCavator 2.0](http://active-xcavator.findmysoft.com/)

> Internet Explorer can automatically download and install ActiveX controls onto your system. Active XCavator tells you what controls have been installed, and enables you to easily remove them.
>
> Active XCavator will list ActiveX controls installed from the Web by IE 3.0 or later. You can see the all the information on the control, such as the name, size and location of the file.
>
> If you have an ActiveX control that is very large, doesn't work properly, or was downloaded by accident, Active XCavator lets you delete it. If you delete a control by mistake, all you have to do is return to the original Web site from which the control was installed and it will automatically be installed again.

Works just great.